# I dont get the expenses of the 31 of the previous months with Activerecord in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When I show the total expend of PUQ theres no problem

`Expend.where(cc: "PUQ").sum(:total)`

But when I want to show by month individually with this code, I Don't get the expenses of the 31, only show 1 to 30 of the month. Right now I dont get the expenses of 31-08-2020

`Expend.where(cc: "PUQ").where(:created_at => ((Date.today.beginning_of_month)- 1.month)..((Date.today.end_of_month) - 1.month)).sum(:total)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: September has 30 days and there fore `- 1.month` = Aug 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these handy Rails methods

```
range = Time.current.advance(months: -1).all_month
# => Sat, 01 Aug 2020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00..Mon, 31 Aug 2020 23:59:59 UTC +00:00


Expend.where(created_at: range)
```

More about [`all_month`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_month)
and about [`advance`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-advance)